# How to create a Ruby DateTime from existing Time.zone for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime, ruby-on-rails-3.2, timezone

I have users entering in dates in a Ruby on Rails website. I parse the dates into a DateTime object with something like:

```
date = DateTime.new(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i, params[:hour].to_i, params[:minute].to_i)
```

or

```
date = DateTime.parse(params[:date])
```

Both `DateTime`s will ***not*** be in the time zone of the user which I previously set with something like:

```
Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
```

How do I parse the above `DateTime`s to be in the right time zone? I know the `DateTime.new` method has a 7th argument for the time offset. Is there an easy way to look up the offset for a time zone in a given time? Or should I be using something other than `DateTime`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `Time.zone.local` if you set `Time.zone` previously:

```
user_time = Time.zone.local(params[:year].to_i, params[:month].to_i, params[:day].to_i, params[:hour].to_i, params[:minute].to_i, 0)
```

Have a look at the [`ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeWithZone.html) documentation.

Comment: For anyone with a Railscasts.com pro account: http://railscasts.com/episodes/106-time-zones-revised

Comment: @wintermeyer I just subscribed to railscasts because of you, thanks.

Comment: please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559402/188574 if you want to accept parameters like 0 or -1 for month and days.

Answer (score 41):

Try:

```
Time.zone = "Pacific Time (US & Canada)"
Time.zone.parse('8-11-2013 23:59:59') #=> Fri, 08 Nov 2013 23:59:59 PST -08:00
```

OR

```
Time.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

OR

```
DateTime.now.in_time_zone("Pacific Time (US & Canada)")
```

Comment: Just to complement the answer here you i'll find in constants all the list of available zones https://apidock.com/rails/TimeZone

Answer (score 25):

You can use the following code to create a `DateTime` object with your desired `TimeZone`.

```
DateTime.new(2013, 6, 29, 10, 15, 30).change(:offset => "+0530")
```

With Ruby v1.9.1, the below line does the same job like a magic.

```
DateTime.new(2013, 6, 29, 10, 15, 30, "+0530")
```

Documentation [here](https://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_1_378/DateTime/new/class)

Comment: And of you have an already existing time with a set timezone you can do DateTime.new(2013, 6,29,10,15,30).change(:offset => known_time.zone)

Comment: This does not result in the desired value.  The point is that the time "10:15:30" should be in the desired time zone, and one wants to get a value out out that: (byebug) p DateTime.new(2015,12,27,0,0,0).change(:offset => 'America/New_York')
Sun, 27 Dec 2015 00:00:00 +0000

Comment: DateTime.new accepts offset as the seventh optional argument. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49559402/188574 for usage.

Comment: Thanks @twnaing. Updated the comment :-)

Answer (score 7):

`DateTime.new` accepts optional **offset** argument (as the seventh) starting from ruby 1.9.1

We can write

```
DateTime.new(2018, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, Time.zone.formatted_offset)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have already a correct DateTime object with the name 'datetime', and you want to copy it, you can simply call the 'getutc' on it and after that use the 'in_time_zone'

```
DateTime.new(datetime.getutc.year, datetime.getutc.month, datetime.getutc.day, time.getutc.hour, time.getutc.min).in_time_zone
```